# SetupFixture does not allow grouped test runs in Resharper

Tags: c#, nunit, resharper, integration-testing

I haved created a class with the [`SetupFixture`](http://www.nunit.org/index.php?p=setupFixture&r=2.6.4) attribute to have a one time setup as needed for my integration test assembly.

```
[SetUpFixture]
public static class IntegrationTestsBase
{
    public static IKernel Kernel;

    [SetUp]
    public static void RunBeforeAnyTests()
    {
        Kernel = new StandardKernel();
        if (Kernel == null)
            throw new Exception("Ninject failure on test base startup!");

        Kernel.Load(new ConfigModule());
        Kernel.Load(new RepositoryModule());
    }

    [TearDown]
    public static void RunAfterAnyTests()
    {
        Kernel.Dispose();
    }
}
```

Resharpers Unit Test Session window has a grouping set to: Projects and Namespaces. However if I use this instance class, Resharpers Unit Test Session says that:

> Ignored: Test should be run explicitly

Even tried running these tests with MsTest runner:

> Result Message: IntegrationTestsBase is an abstract class.

I have tried to wrap this class to a namespace but nothing changed. If I run individual tests one-by-one it gets runned, however I cannot run them all from the GUI.

How can I fix this issue to be able to run all the tests included in this assembly?

Using NUnit 2.6.4, Resharper 2015.2 and VS2015 update 1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your Testclass doesn't need to be static as it gets instantiated by the Testframework and static classes typically can't be instantiated.

The quickest fix is to remove the `static` keyword except from your `Kernel` property.

```
[SetUpFixture]
public class IntegrationTestsBase
{
    public static IKernel Kernel;

    [SetUp]
    public void RunBeforeAnyTests()
    {
        Kernel = new StandardKernel();
        if (Kernel == null)
            throw new Exception("Ninject failure on test base startup!");

        Kernel.Load(new ConfigModule());
        Kernel.Load(new RepositoryModule());
    }

    [TearDown]
    public void RunAfterAnyTests()
    {
        Kernel.Dispose();
    }
}
```

Keep in mind that whatever you put in `Kernel` is now shared so if this test is run with multiple threads, the class in `Kernel` is not isolated to a single test. Which is something you should either be aware of or compensate for.